# R Shiny Display Notification

Tags: r, shiny

Is there any way I can pull a csv file from an email notification in Shiny app and display?

showNotification() displays a message in the UI but am curious to know how to pull the attached csv for display.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes there is actually, I tried it in my project. Let me show you a sample:

```html
output$examplenotification <- renderMenu({
    
    nots <- apply(read.csv("file.csv"), 1, function(row) {
      notificationItem(text = row[["To"]],icon = shiny::icon("envelope"), status = "success")
    })
    dropdownMenu(type = "notifications", .list = nots)

  })
```

Hope it helps.